# Using Fubini's Theorem in Contour Integrals proof

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, operator-theory, spectral-theory, banach-algebras

I have a few questions regarding the following proof:

Suppose that $\mathcal{A}$ is a unital Banach algebra, and that $g$ is a complex-valued function which is analytic on $\sigma(a)$ while $f$ is a complex-valued function which is analytic on $g(\sigma(a))$. Then $(f \circ g)(a) = f(g(a))$.

**Proof:** Let $V$ be an open neighbourhood of $g(\sigma(a))$ upon which $f$ is analytic and consider $U = g^{-1}(V)$, an open neighbourhood of $\sigma(a)$. Let $\Gamma_{1}$ be a system of closed contours in $U$ such that 
\begin{align}
 &\text{Ind}_{\Gamma_{1}}(\lambda) = 1~~\text{for all } \lambda \in \sigma(a)~~\text{and}~~\text{Ind}_{\Gamma_{1}}(\lambda) \neq 0~~\text{implies that }\lambda \in U.
\end{align}
Let $\Gamma_{2}$ be a system of closed contours in $V$ such that
\begin{align}
\text{Ind}_{\Gamma_{2}}(\beta) = 1 \text{ for all }\beta \in g(\sigma(a))~~\text{and }\text{Ind}_{\Gamma_{2}}(\beta)=1~~\text{for all }\beta \in g(\Gamma_{1}).
\end{align}
Then we get 
\begin{align}
(f \circ g)(a) &= \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma_{1}}(f \circ g)(z)(z-a)^{-1}dz
\\& = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{1}}f(g(z))(z-a)^{-1}dz
\\& = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_{\Gamma_{1}}\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma_{2}}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}dw(z-a)^{-1}dz
\\& = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma_{2}}f(w) \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma_{1}}(w - g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dzdw
\\& = \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\Gamma_{2}}f(w)(w-g(a))^{-1}dw
\\& = f(g(a)).
\end{align}

**Questions:**
In equation 3 of the proof I assume we are using Cauchy Integral Formula. In equation 4, it seems that Fubini's theorem is being used, but I don't see how, since we have a Banach space valued integral $\int_{\Gamma_{1}}...dz$ and a complex valued integral $\int_{\Gamma_{2}}...dw$. How is this step obtained? Does it not matter that the one integral maps to $\mathcal{A}$ and the other to $\mathbb{C}$. If possible could you expand on how this equation is obtained?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: In the fourth line, you forgot the $f(w)$. It's back in the fifth line, so no permanent damage done. Yes, it's Cauchy's integral formula, and then Fubini. How precisely you justify the application of Fubini's theorem depends on what sort of $\mathcal{A}$-valued integral you are using. But since everything is continuous and the domains of integration are compact, it's fairly straightforward. (However, I'm too lazy now to write a full answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nice things about Functional Analysis is that you can generally reduce to the scalar case by applying a linear functional to everything, rearranging scalar integrals, and then pulling the functional back outside. Then, knowing that you have enough functionals to separate points allows you to remove the functional from both sides of the resulting equation. You do, however, need the existence of the integrals without the functionals, or to define the integrals by how they interact with functionals. But the theorems to interchange orders of integration can be reduced to corresponding scalar cases.

**In full detail:** The Banach algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is a Banach space and its dual space $\mathcal{A}^{\star}$ consists of all continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{A}$. Suppose you have a continuous rectifiable curve $\gamma(t) : [0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ and a continuous function $f : \Omega\subseteq\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{A}$ on an open region $\Omega$ containing the image of the curve $\gamma$. Then you can define a Riemann-Stieljes integral
$$
           \int_{\gamma} f(z)dz = \lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0} \sum_{j}f(\gamma(t_j^{\star}))\{\gamma(t_j)-\gamma(t_{j-1})\},
$$
where the partition $\mathcal{P}$ consists of subdivision points $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \cdots < t_n = 1$ and intermediate points $t_j^{\star} \in [t_{j-1},t_j]$. The right side converges in the norm of $\mathcal{A}$ as $\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0$. If $\Phi \in \mathcal{A}^{\star}$, then $\Phi$ is continuous and linear, which gives the existence of the following limits, independent of the choice of $\Phi$:
\begin{align}
         \Phi\left(\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz\right)& =\Phi\left(\lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{j}f(\gamma(t_j^{\star}))\{\gamma(t_j)-\gamma(t_{j-1})\}\right) \\
   & = \lim_{\|\mathcal{P}\|\rightarrow 0}\sum_{j}\Phi(f(t_j^{\star}))\{\gamma(t_j)-\gamma(t_{j-1})\} \\
   & = \int_{\gamma}\Phi(f(z))dz
\end{align}
The final integral on the right exists because the vector integral on the far left exists, and the two are related as shown above. You can easily throw in a scalar function $\alpha(z)$, too:
$$
          \Phi\left(\int_{\gamma}\alpha(z)f(z)dz\right)=\int_{\gamma}\alpha(z)\Phi(f(z))dz.
$$
This becomes a fundamental building block for dealing with integrals.

Next, in your case, you have integrals
$$
       I=\int_{\Gamma_1}\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}dw\right)(z-a)^{-1}dz.
$$
These are defined as iterated integrals. The inner integrand is a continuous function of $w$ for fixed $z \in \Gamma_1$, and the inner integral gives a continuous function of $z$. So you can then multiply the scalar value of this inner integral by $(z-a)^{-1}$ and integrate with respect to $z$. In fact, by continuity of Banach algebra multiplication, you can also write $I$ as
$$
           I = \int_{\Gamma_1}\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dw\right)dz.
$$
Now apply a linear functional $\Phi\in\mathcal{A}^{\star}$ and apply our identity twice:
\begin{align}
       \Phi(I) & =\int_{\Gamma_1}\Phi\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{1}dw\right)dz \\
         & = \int_{\Gamma_1}\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)\Phi((w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1})dw\right)dz
\end{align}
This reduces everything to scalar integrals. The function $\Phi(\cdots)$ has all of the properties of the vector function in terms of joint continuity, etc., which then allows you to interchange orders of integration and to apply our identity in reverse:
\begin{align}
   \Phi(I) & = \int_{\Gamma_2}\int_{\Gamma_1}f(w)\Phi((w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1})dzdw \\
& = \int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)\int_{\Gamma_1}\Phi((w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1})dzdw \\
     & = \int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)\Phi\left(\int_{\Gamma_1}(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dz\right)dw \\
     & = \Phi\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)\int_{\Gamma_1}(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dzdw\right)
\end{align}
Because this is true for all linear functional $\Phi \in \mathcal{A}^{\star}$, then
$$
        I = \int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)\int_{\Gamma_1}(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dzdw
$$
And that is exactly what you want, where the end result is that you can interchange orders of integration for the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Could you be more specific as to how you would apply this to the above case?

Comment: First, tell me how you are defining the integrals. For example, suppose you are using Riemann integrals, which suffice here. An integral is a limit of a Riemann sum. Apply a continuous linear functional to the integral. You can interchange the limit of a sum with the linear functional (because it is continuous) and you have the limit of a scalar sum that is an ordinary Riemann integral. Once the linear function is applied to the vector terms of the inner integral, you now a scalar problem. Change order, and pull the functional back out. Is that explicit enough?

Comment: @Moses : I forgot to ping you with my comment.

Comment: Not completely, but to start with are you saying that if we have a continuous linear functional say $g$ then
\begin{align}
g\bigg(\int f(x)dx \bigg) &= g \sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}f(x_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})
\\& = g \lim\limits_{m \to \infty} \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}f(x_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})
\\& = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}g\bigg( \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m}f(x_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1})\bigg)
\\& = \lim\limits_{m \to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{m}g\bigg(f(x_{i})(x_{i}-x_{i-1}) \bigg)
\end{align}
How does this connect with my question?

Comment: @Moses This should be a Riemann sum, instead, not an infinite sum. Finally, $g(f(x_i)(x_i-x_{i-1}))=g(f(x_i))(x_i-x_{i-1})$, which turns the right side into a scalar Riemann integral $\int g(f(x))dx$. So $g\left(\int fdx\right)=\int g(f(x))dx$, allowing you to freely move functionals inside the integral, and turn everything into scalar integrals. Then you can manipulate scalar integrals, and pull the functional back outside.

Comment: Okay I understand how that works for Riemann integrals. But in your example both the Riemann integral and the continuous functional $g$ take values in $\mathbb{R}$. My problem is with contour integration, I have a definition that states that for Banach space valued functions $f: \Gamma(I) \to \mathcal{A}$, where $\Gamma: I \to \mathbb{C}$ is a contour, we can define the integral$$\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz := \int_{a}^{b}f(\Gamma(t))\Gamma'(t)dt \in \mathcal{A}$$

Comment: where I assume that  $\int_{a}^{b}f(\Gamma(t))\Gamma'(t)dt$ is a Bochner integral. But then I am also aware of contour integration for complex valued functions $f: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ which is defined similarly as can be seen in [this wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration).

Comment: In the proof I use, it seems that they are used interchangeably. Consider the nested integral in equation three of  the original proof, we have a complex valued contour integral times an element of $\mathcal{A}$, this is given as  $\int_{\Gamma_{2}}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}dw(z-a)^{-1}$, then taking $(z-a)^{-1}$ into the integral gives the $\mathcal{A}$ valued contour integral $\int_{\Gamma_{2}}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dw$. I don't see how this follows? How are these types (Banach space valued and complex valued) of contour integrals related? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: @Moses : NOTE: In the example I gave you, $f$ was vector-valued function. $g$ is applied to vectors because it's in the dual of the vector space, which is the Banach algebra in your case. The dual space consists of continuous linear functions over $\mathbb{C}$ if you're working on a complex space. Nothing in the arguments gets changed. $f(w)(w-g(z))$ is scalar and $(z-a)^{-1}$ is vector. Riemann (or Riemann-Stieltjes) integral is good enough for what you're doing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29047/discussion-between-moses-and-trialanderror).

Comment: @Moses : I'll just add more information into the answer for you.

Comment: @Moses : Full details have been added. It's worth seeing a careful analysis just once.

Comment: Very nice answer, thanks, much appreciated. Could I inquire about one things, how did you use the continuity of multiplication to rewrite $I$ as $$
           I = \int_{\Gamma_1}\left(\int_{\Gamma_2}f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}(z-a)^{-1}dw\right)dz.
$$? You can answer on chat if you prefer.

Comment: @Moses : Applying a continuous multiplication operator is no different that applying a continuous linear functional. I'll let you work out that detail.

Comment: @Moses : Define a multiplication operator $M(y)=y(z-a)^{-1}$. This does not depend on the variable of integration $w$. $I=\int\int M(f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1})dw dz=\int M\left(\int f(w)(w-g(z))^{-1}dw\right)dz$. This follows in the same way using Riemann sums because $M$ is a linear continuous operator on $\mathcal{A}$.

Comment: So what I did was correct?

Comment: @Moses : I think all of the steps in your original argument are justified.

Comment: Okay thanks for all the assistance.